# Windows Patches/Updates in a hosting enviornment

Tags: windows-update, automatic-updates

I'm looking for a good tool besides WSUS that will allow me to update Windows 2000/2003/2008 servers that are part of a domain/in a different domain/standalone enviornment.

The current products I'm looking at are
[Kaseya](http://www.kaseya.com/)
[Security Manager Plus](http://www.manageengine.com/products/security-manager/patch-management.html)

Does anyone have any experience with these tools? How do they work in your environment? Are there any other tools that someone can recommend so I can take a look at it as well?

Comment: Are you looking for something to manage OS patches only?

Comment: @JohnThePro Yes John, Patches only

Answer (score 1):

[Remote RebootX](http://dougzuck.com/) is good. Was free, now have to pay, except if you kept the free version.

I guess SCCM from Microsoft is not an option ?

Comment: +1 for SCCM. Ability to schedule maintenance windows and deploy different sets of updates via different update lists is extremely handy.

Comment: @ChrisMcK can SCCM work across domains that don't have existing forests between them?

Comment: @Rome sure it can, through certificates. Even workgroups

Answer (score 0):

Is it out of the question to let the servers reboot themselves? I use this for a good number of our servers through Group Policy and it has never let me down. Note that these servers are only rebooted in the wee hours of the morning and their uptime during that time is of no concern.

Comment: Hi Joel, unfortunately we need the ability to control exactly when the servers go down for their reboot. If 50 servers were rebooted and 10 of them don't come up then we'd have our hands full.